# MediaStreamTrack read only properties

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, jitsi

Running into some issues using webrtc with an sfu. Occasionally we run into problems where the video track on an incoming stream is `muted: true` and `readystate: "muted"`. Those are read only properties so I know I am not setting them anywhere. Are those properties determined by the browser (chrome) or are they explicitly set on the stream/track by the sfu? Any help is welcome, but I'd love to see some documentation somewhere about this. For reference, the sfu we are using is Jitsi Video Bridge.